# validating xml with XML::LibXML

Tags: xml, perl, xsd, xsd-validation

I am trying the following xml against xsd using the following code

```
my $schema = XML::LibXML::Schema->new(location => $xsd); 
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;  
my $doc = $parser->parse_file($xml); 
eval { $schema->validate( $doc ) };  
if ( my $ex = $@ ) {
 print "error"
}     
else {
    print "Schema validated ok";
}
```

even that my schema is validated with ok ,
i get on this line this warning /error

**http error : No such file or directory**

worth to mention the xsd is on my local desk
and the error emit on this line

```
my $schema = XML::LibXML::Schema->new(location => $xsd);
```

and the $xsd have the location of my xml file c:\users\vivo\validate\xml.xsd

below are the first synopsis form my schema

```
?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://ce.omb.edu/schema/34"
    xmlns:vivo="http://ce.omb.edu/schema/vivo/0.4"
    targetNamespace="http://ce.omb.edu/schema/subversion/vivi/2.0"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    version="2.0">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://ce.omb.edu/schema/vivo/0.4" schemaLocation="c:/users/vivo/desktop/validate/vivo.xsd"/>
```

could someone help why I get this warning /error message ?

Comment: What line of your code is emitting the error?

Comment: this line : my $schema = XML::LibXML::Schema->new(location => $xsd);

Comment: And what is the value of `$xsd`? (please edit these pieces of information into the question instead of posting them in comments)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting:

```
die "$xsd is not a file" unless -f $xsd;
```

before your `my $schema` line, run it again and see what it says. Based on the comments above, it will tell you where it is looking. It looks like either the filename is wrong altogether or `$xsd` is not an absolute path and the current working directory from the point of view of the script is not the one you think it is.

If that's the case, start by having a look at http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html to see what you can do to fix it.